# React Navigation: Navigate Back To Root using NavigationActions.reset, goBack and getStateForAction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Say I've navigated through 4 screens in my StackNavigator App and now I want to go back to the first screen. There seems to be three different ways to do this and they do navigate to where I want to do, however each way has an animation that cycles through each previous screen.

Is there a clean way to navigate from `SCREEN_D` to `SCREEN_A`?

In other words, I don't want to see `SCREEN_C` and `SCREEN_B` a split of a second before seeing `SCREEN_A` when navigating backwards from `SCREEN_D`

```
navigation.navigate(SCREEN_A);
...
navigation.navigate(SCREEN_B);
...
navigation.navigate(SCREEN_C);
...
navigation.navigate(SCREEN_D);
```

Three ways to do this:

1.

```
return this.props.navigation
               .dispatch(NavigationActions.reset(
                 {
                    index: 0,
                    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'SCREEN_A'})]
                  }));
```

2.

```
 const {SCREEN_B_KEY} = this.props.navigation.state.params
 this.props.navigation.goBack(SCREEN_B_KEY)
```

3.

```
const defaultGetStateForAction = Navigation.router.getStateForAction;

Navigation.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) =>{
  if(action.type === "Navigation/BACK"){
    const routes = [
      {routeName: 'First'},
    ];
    return {
      ...state,
      routes,
      index: 0,
    };
  }
  return defaultGetStateForAction (action,state);
}
```

Comment: did you try Navigator.dismiss(); ?

Comment: I don't see that in the docs. Do you have a link? @Codesingh

Comment: There's a pull request for this: https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/pull/2520

Answer (score 28):

react-navigation has `popToTop` and we can use it like blow

```
this.props.navigation.popToTop()
```

Comment: does this unmount all the screens from the stack ?

Comment: according to the official [Doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#poptotop): `it jump back to the top route in the stack, dismissing all other screens`

Comment: please check navigation is not undefined

Answer (score 7):

Here's a quick fix.
This will remove ALL transitions when navigating (forward or backward).

```
const Nav = StackNavigator({
  Screens
},{
  transitionConfig,
  navigationOptions
});
```

in transitionConfig add this:

```
const transitionConfig = () => ({
    transitionSpec: {
      duration: 0,
      timing: Animated.timing,
      easing: Easing.step0,
    },
  })
```

The transitionConfig is a function that returns an object that overrides default screen transitions. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack

- if someone knows a way to change animations on single navigation, I'd love to hear how!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by using the `popToTop` method from the [Navigation prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html). Also, if you are using redux, you should update your [Redux integration](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/redux-integration.html).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

For 2020 / react-navigation-stack I use the following code when setting up the StackNavigator:

```
import { createStackNavigator, CardStyleInterpolators } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { Easing } from 'react-native';

const Navigator = createStackNavigator({
  // ...
}, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
    const animation = navigation.getParam('_animation');
    return {
      // ...
      cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS,
      ...(animation === 'back' && {
        gestureDirection: 'horizontal-inverted',
      }),
      ...(animation === 'skip' && {
        transitionSpec: {
          open: { animation: 'timing', config: { duration: 0, easing: Easing.step1 }, },
          close: { animation: 'timing', config: { duration: 0, easing: Easing.step0 }, },
        },
      }),
    };
  },
});
```

and the the _animation param to override the animation style

```
// replace to a route not in the stack normally creates a forward animation, but
// we want a backwards animation
this.props.navigation.dispatch(
  StackActions.replace({ routeName: 'Login', params: { _animation: 'back' } })
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I did simpler version of this: ```defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {``` ... ```const skipAnimation = navigation.getParam('skipAnimation') ?? false``` ... ```animationEnabled: !skipAnimation,```. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator#animationenabled

Answer (score 0):

Also spent some time on this, let me sum up what I discovered, there are multiple solutions/workarounds for this:

## 1) Use `CardStackStyleInterpolator`

The [pull request](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/pull/2520) mentioned by [Cristiano Santos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736007/cristiano-santos) seems to be merged. So you can load the `CardStackStyleInterpolator` with this import:

```
import CardStackStyleInterpolator from 'react-navigation/src/views/CardStack/CardStackStyleInterpolator'
```

To apply it like this:

```
const YourStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Screen1: { screen: Screen1 },
    Screen2: { screen: Screen2 },
}, {
    transitionConfig: () => ({
        screenInterpolator: (props) => CardStackStyleInterpolator.forHorizontal(props)
    })
});
```

In my case, I just jump to the next screen like:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Modal_AddGoodClass');
```

But in my reducer, I reset the navigator when the `Modal_AddGoodClass` screen is triggered:

```
const NewExportReceiptNavigationReducer = (state, action) => {
    // Default stuff

    let newStateBuffer = newState || state;

    if (action) {
        if (action.type === 'Navigation/NAVIGATE') {
            if (action.routeName === 'Modal_AddGoodClass') {
                newStateBuffer = {
                    index:  0,
                    routes: [
                        newStateBuffer.routes[newStateBuffer.routes.length - 1]
                    ]
                };
            }
        }
    }

    return newStateBuffer;
};

module.exports = NewExportReceiptNavigationReducer;
```

This works pretty well, except the fact, that still a "back" animation is used instead of a "forward" one.

You can also find [here](https://github.com/94cstyles/react-navigation-test) some example code that uses `CardStackStyleInterpolator`.

## 2) Overwrite `getStateForAction`:

As [Fendrian](https://github.com/Fendrian) mentioned [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/351#issuecomment-302257857) you can overwrite `getStateForAction` of your router to avoid the navigator to go back. This seems to work except for the "swipe back" gesture on iOS:

```
Nav = StackNavigator(navScreens, navOptions);
const defaultGetStateForAction = Nav.router.getStateForAction;
Nav.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
  if (
    state &&
    action.type === NavigationActions.BACK &&
    (
      state.routes[state.index].routeName === 'Login' ||
      state.routes[state.index].routeName === 'Main'
    )
  ) {
    // Returning null indicates stack end, and triggers exit
    return null;
  }
  return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
};
```

[image: nov-05-2017 11-34-07]

Answer (score 0):

This is my working solution for reset back to home (root) without creating new route

```
if(this.categoriesNav.state.nav.index >0){
    let k = this.categoriesNav.state.nav.routes[1].key;
    this.categoriesNav.dispatch(NavigationActions.back({key: k})); }
```

`categoriesNav` is referenced to my stack navigator

Answer (score 0):

I think I got a solution as described in this article https://medium.com/async-la/custom-transitions-in-react-navigation-2f759408a053 that explains how navigation works pretty well (would strongly recommend reading it as it's a pretty quick read and helped me get a better understanding of how transitions work).

Here's a gif of a sample navigator that has smooth transitions for moving multiple screens back and forth:
[Navigator Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1BRt.gif)
(Sorry it's a link, I don't have enough rep yet to embed a video so I had to do a link). However, this shows how the navigator whose source code is below behaves.

Essentially what happens is if you want to go from screen 4 on your stack to 1, you can set the opacity of 2 and 3 to 0, so then the transition will appear to go from 4 to 1.

Here's the source code for the navigator:

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import ScreenA from './ScreenA';
import ScreenB from './ScreenB';
import ScreenC from './ScreenC';
import ScreenD from './ScreenD';

const OuterNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
    ScreenA: {
        screen: ScreenA,
        navigationOptions: {
            //Set header stuff here
            headerTintColor: "#fff",
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#4444aa',
            },
            headerTitle: "Screen A"
        }
    },
    ScreenB: {
        screen: ScreenB,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerTintColor: "#fff",
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#44aa44',
            },
            headerTitle: "Screen B"
        }
    },
    ScreenC: {
        screen: ScreenC,

        navigationOptions: {
            headerTintColor: "#fff",
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#aa4444',
            },
            headerTitle: "Screen C"
        }
    },
    ScreenD: {
        screen: ScreenD,

        navigationOptions: {
            headerTintColor: "#fff",
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#44aaaa',
            },
            headerTitle: "Screen D"
        }
    },
},

{
    // Sets initial screen to screen A
    initialRouteName: 'ScreenA',

    // Can be changed to whatever you prefer
    headerMode: 'float',

    // This line makes a transparent background so the navigator can be wrapped in a background image
    // (this was an issue I struggled with and figured there's a change someone else might be as well)
    cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '00000000', shadowColor: '000000' },
    transitionConfig: () => ({
        // This link exlpains this in detail: 
        // https://medium.com/async-la/custom-transitions-in-react-navigation-2f759408a053
        containerStyle: {
            // This also has to do with having a background image
            backgroundColor: '00000000',
        },
        transitionSpec: {
            // Sets speed for transition (lower -> faster)
            duration: 500,
            useNativeDriver: true,
        },
        screenInterpolator: sceneProps => {
            // Parses scene props
            const { position, layout, scene, index, scenes } = sceneProps

            // Grabs height and width of screen
            const toIndex = index
            const thisSceneIndex = scene.index
            const height = layout.initHeight
            const width = layout.initWidth

            // Grab index of last screen
            const lastSceneIndex = scenes[scenes.length - 1].index

            // Calculates change in indices
            const deltaScene = (lastSceneIndex - toIndex == 0) ? 1 : (lastSceneIndex - toIndex);

            let translateX = position.interpolate({
                inputRange: [thisSceneIndex - 1, thisSceneIndex],
                // Adjusts how the output get scaled
                outputRange: [width / deltaScene, 0],
            });

            const translateY = position.interpolate({
                // Not used, but in the link they use this for vertical transitions
                // If you're interested in that this would do it
                inputRange: [0, thisSceneIndex],
                outputRange: [height, 0]
            });

            // MAGIC HAPPENS HERE:
            // Test whether we're skipping back more than one screen
            // and slide from bottom if true
            if (lastSceneIndex - toIndex > 1) {
                // If you want the screen to which you are transitioning to not move
                // have return; in this if block (see link). If you want behaviour as 
                // shown in the GIF then leave this
                if (scene.index === toIndex) {
                    return { transform: [{ translateX }] }
                }
                // BIG MAGIC HERE
                // Hide all screens in between
                if (scene.index !== lastSceneIndex) return { opacity: 0 }

            }
            return { transform: [{ translateX }] }
        },
    }),
}
);
```

So, for example, let's say your stack is something like [A, B, C, D] (so D is on top). lastSceneIndex grabs the index of the last scene (in this case D). DeltaScene calculates how much the scenes are changing. DeltaScene will only be != 1 when one goes back more than 1 screen. If you aren't familiar with how translateX works, I would strongly recommend reading the afore mentioned link; the reason why the output range is [width/deltaScene, 0] is before the animation starts, the screens are stacked on top of each other and then the animation scales will spread them out like [A][B][C][D] where each screen is width/deltaScene away. In this example, deltaScene is 3, so B is width / 3 to the right of A, C is 2 * width / 3 to the right of A, and D is 3 * width / 3 = width to the right of A, which is what we want. Without deltaScene, D would fly off to the right 3 times faster than A comes onto the screen, which makes for an ugly transition.

Also, I doubt anyone needs to see this but just in case, here's how it gets used in App.js (the provider is for redux, so that can probably be omitted if you don't want to deal with that)

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <ImageBackground source={require('./assets/background.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage} resizeMode='cover'>
    <AppNavigator />
  </ImageBackground>
</Provider>
...
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
  }
});
```

I really hope this helps!
I'm still pretty new to react native and whatnot, so if I made any mistakes or there's any room for further improvement or explanation, please say so in the comments for me/anyone else that might see this!