# Remove last route from react navigation stack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So, I have the following screens:

```
- ChatList
- NewRoom
- ChatRoom
```

Basically, I don't want to go back to `Start a new chat` from the just-created chat room ... but instead go directly into the chat rooms list. So far, I came up with the following:

```
const prevGetStateForActionChatStack = ChatStack.router.getStateForAction

ChatStack.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
    if (state && action.type === 'RemovePreviousScreen') {
        const routes = state.routes.slice( 0, state.routes.length - 2 ).concat( state.routes.slice( -1 ) )
        return {
            ...state,
            routes,
            index: routes.length - 1
        }
    }
    return prevGetStateForActionChatStack(action, state)
}
```

And it theoretically works ... but there is a weird animation when removing the previous route after getting to the new room, as follows. Let me know if you guys have any solution to this issue ...

[image: Example]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### In react-navigation@3.0

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#reset

### In react-navigation@6.0

The reset action is replaced by replace.

```
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(   
    StackActions.replace('Profile', {user: 'jane',}) 
);
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#replace

Answer (score 2):

From your code it seems you are using `react-navigation`.

React-Navigation has a reset action that allows you to set the screen stack.
For example: 
In your case,

Screen 1: Chat room

Screen 2: Chat list

If you want to remove the chatroom screen from your stack you need to write it as

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'chatlist'})
  ]
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

This will reset your stack to only one screen as initial screen that is chatlist.
`actions` array can have multiple routes and `index` defines the active route.

For further details refer the following link:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions

[Resetting the navigation stack for the home screen (React Navigation and React Native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090884/resetting-the-navigation-stack-for-the-home-screen-react-navigation-and-react-n)

Comment: Basically, I want to get rid of the "middle" screen when creating a new conversation, so I can get back from "chat room" to "rooms list" directly, instead of having to get back to "new room" screen. Will give your idea a try. The only wrong thing with my code is this weird animation .. and from what I know, reset has no animation either ? Correct me if I'm wrong. Will give it a try and come back with a reply.

Comment: yes reset animation doesn't provide an animation by default unless you choose to implement it.

Comment: For those arriving here from Google, in v4, you need to use StackActions.reset().

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use the following to change the animation:

```
export const doNotAnimateWhenGoingBack = () => ({
  // NOTE https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1865 to avoid back animation
  screenInterpolator: sceneProps => {
    if (Platform.isIos) {
      // on ios the animation actually looks good! :D
      return CardStackStyleInterpolator.forHorizontal(sceneProps);
    }
    if (
      sceneProps.index === 0 &&
      sceneProps.scene.route.routeName !== 'nameOfScreenYouWannaGoTo' &&
      sceneProps.scenes.length > 2
    )
      return null;

    return CardStackStyleInterpolator.forVertical(sceneProps);
  },
});
```

and use it as follows:

```
const Stack = StackNavigator(
  {
  ...screens...
  },
  {
    transitionConfig: doNotAnimateWhenGoingBack,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the useNavigate for navigation you can clear the previous route like this :

const navigate = useNavigate();

navigate("/chats",{replace: true,});

Use this replace true to clear the previous route.