# How to handel the routing of screens of createStackNavigator nested inside createDrawerNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have screens in stacknavigator which are nested inside DrawerNavigator. I wanted to restart the screens in DrawerNavigator when clicked.

System flow Architecture:

App.js::

StackNavigator:

1. Login.js
2. ScreensSetup.js

ScreensSetup.js consists the following::

a. Stack screens as:

```
  const FirstStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    First: {
      screen: Dashboard,
    },
  });

  const SecondStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Second: {
      screen: Workorders,
    },
  });
```

b. DrawerNavigator nested with above stacked screens as:

```
  const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Dashboard: {
      screen: FirstStackNavigator,
    },
    Workorders: {
      screen: SecondStackNavigator,
    },
  },
  {
    contentComponent: DrawerContent ,
    initialRouteName: 'Dashboard',
  });
```

I am able to navigate to "Workorders" from "ScreensSetup" by:

```
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Workorders');
```

This works perfectly.

But I need to restart the screen. So, I used:
For reseting ScreensSetup:

```
const navigateAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "ScreensSetup" })],
  });

  this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
```

This works perfectly.

For reseting Workorders:

```
const navigateAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "Workorders" })],
  });

  this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
```

This gives me error:

```
 Error: Error: There is no route defined for key Workorders.                        
    │ Must be one of: 'Login','ScreensSetup'
```

I simply wanted to reset the screen when clicked on menus on drawer naviagtor. I am completely messed up with this navigation. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go to initialRoute with react-navigation when exiting a child stack navigator inside a drawer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063950/how-to-go-to-initialroute-with-react-navigation-when-exiting-a-child-stack-navig)

Comment: @Remeus This does not helped me. I wanted to reset the menu's screen of drawer navigator which has been pressed. It just resumes now. How can it be reset ?

Comment: What's the difference between resetting the screen when you leave and resetting the screen when you arrive?

Comment: I load data from api on one of the screen of the menu of drawer Navigator. I just wanted to fetch the data again when menu on the drawer is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close all screens and go back to the beginning, use the `popToTop`'function.

The `popToTop` action takes you back to the first screen in the stack, dismissing all the others. It's functionally identical to `StackActions.pop({n: currentIndex})`.

**Usage**

```js
import { StackActions } from 'react-navigation';

this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop());
```

Comment: This does not helped me. This rest the stack of screens. I wanted to reset the menu's screen of drawer navigator which has been pressed. It just resumes now. How can it be reset ?

Comment: Code cannot be posted here. `Select an answer`, `complete the questions`, and `post the new questions`. `Reset` can be done by using the reset used in the question.