# Unmount all previously mounted screens to exit the app on back press

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a requirement in which I need to exit the app when the back button is pressed. Basically I tried with the `BackHandler` API, which worked but with certain limitations. So in my case, I feel the best way is to unmount all previously mounted components so the current screen becomes the first screen in the stack.

**I have the following screens:**

Login
OtpVerification
Name
Email
.
.
. and more

What I need is that when I am on the **Name** screen, if someone presses the back button, the app should exit. But if someone is on the **Email** screen, the user should be able to go back upto **Name** screen only.

**Snippets using BackHandler**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    .
    .
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this._handleBackPress);
}
.
.
.
.
_handleBackPress = () => {
    BackHandler.exitApp();
};
.
.
.
.
_onPress = () => {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this._handleBackPress);
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Email", { name: this.state.name });
};
```

Comment: what version of react-navigation are you using?

Comment: @LonelyCpp Version 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this would be to reset the stack navigator before navigating to the Name screen.

Use the `reset` action in react-navigation to do this. [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/4.x/stack-actions.html#reset)

A quick example of a function that does this is -

react-navigation 5 - use [`CommonActions`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html#reset)

```js
import { CommonActions } from "@react-navigation/native";

reset = (routeName) => {
  return navigation.dispatch(
    CommonActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      routes: [{ name: routeName }],
    })
  );
};
```

react-navigation v4.x

```js
reset = (routeName) => {
  return this.props.navigation.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName })],
    })
  );
};
```

put this in the `OtpVerification` screen and call `reset('NameScreen')` when navigating to `NameScreen`

related answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43121263/3262983

Comment: this doesnt look like its for version 5. Also am not sure if this is going to exit the app as I tried something similar to this and it is always taking me to Login screen.

Comment: I've added an example for version 5. Try it :)

Comment: So how should I call reset? Before `this.props.navigation.navigate("NameScreen");`

Comment: don't call navigate! reset will navigate to whatever screen you give it. just call `reset("NameScreen");`

Comment: Great!! It does what I was looking for. Just one thing, when my app exits, it stays in the background. Any workaround to **exit it completely**?

Comment: It does actually close the app completely. If you're talking about the "recent apps" in android, that will require some android specific config. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762763/how-to-remove-application-from-recent-application-list