# The action 'Navigation/RESET' was not handled by any navigation

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am stuck with an error. When I am trying to reset the screen navigation stack, I am getting this error `The action 'Navigation/RESET' was not handled by any navigation`

My code to reset the navigation is :

```
 let resetAction = StackActions.reset({
       key: null,
       index: 0,
       actions: [
         NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'ScreenName' })
       ]
    })
 this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

Please if u can suggest me any solution, that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In version 5.x, the way you can reset the navigation is changed. you can use :

```
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
this.props.navigation.dispatch(
  StackActions.popToTop()
);
```

To pop all page redirects from the stack and then go back to first screen. ([view it on expo](https://snack.expo.io/@ya3ya6/play_stack_navigation_redux))

Or you can use:

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 1,
    routes: [
      { name: 'Home' },
      {
        name: 'Profile',
        params: { user: 'jane' },
      },
      ...
    ],
  })
);
```

To reset your navigation state to an initial state.

Here is a [live demo on snack expo](https://snack.expo.io/@ya3ya6/play_stack_navigation_redux) (use android tab, go from home to `details` page, then `page 3`, then press reset. you can see it's now on home page and if you press back, it will exit.) (the code for `popToTop` is on line 44)

Docs: [pop to top action](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions#poptotop) [reset action](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions#reset)

Ps: If you're not using version 5.x , first make sure you have a route called `ScreenName` (since you're using : `routeName: 'ScreenName'`, and if it didn't fix it, try other codes to reset, like: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090884/resetting-the-navigation-stack-for-the-home-screen-react-navigation-and-react-n) )

Comment: @ManiKantTiwari No problem, happy coding :)