# how to switch state of a screen in react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to switch the focused state of let's say screen A , so once I'm there I went to useEffect and added my code :

```
useEffect(() =>{  
navigation.dispatch(
      CommonActions.reset({
      state: false,
      })
    );
  }, []);
```

from the Docs that's what I found it may do the task , but unfortunately it did not work , it fires an error saying :

> can not read property length of undefined

could you please to fix this error .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resetting the navigation stack for the home screen (React Navigation and React Native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090884/resetting-the-navigation-stack-for-the-home-screen-react-navigation-and-react-n)

Comment: I see that the link it shows how to dispatch a navigation event or adding params .. not changing focus state from true to false