# Navigation reset not work as expected in React Native - auto back to previous screen

Tags: android, react-native, navigation

My current route: Home -> C -> D -> E

I use navigation reset at E like this:

```
navigation.dispatch(
      CommonActions.reset({
        index: 2,
        routes: [
          {name: HOME},
          {name: A},
          {name: B, params: {paramB}},
        ],
      }),
    );
```

Expected: Focus on screen B

Actual: Focus on screen A (It render both A,B then back to A - only happen in Android).

- When I back, app crash with "The specified child already has a parent. you must call removeview() on the child's parent first" or "index 0 size 0" or blank screen

I do it wrong? Can I only render focus screen on stack?

Navigation reset not work as expected in React Native, it auto back to previous screen

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090884/resetting-the-navigation-stack-for-the-home-screen-react-navigation-and-react-n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090884/resetting-the-navigation-stack-for-the-home-screen-react-navigation-and-react-n). refer this one

Comment: tks but it not the same problem